# A chain rule in the space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'$

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Many result of calculus hold for distributions. Anyway I found nothing about a chain rule for derivtives of distributions  (obviously, when they are of the function type, hence elements of $L^1_{loc}\subset\mathcal{D}'$).

Any possibly non technical but interesting result?

Comment: Well, in the first place, the composition of two locally integrable functions is not locally integrable in general.

Comment: A distribution $f = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n$ where $f_n = f \ast n \phi(nx)$ then for $g$ continuous or ... define $f \circ g = \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(g(.))$ if the latter converges in the sense of distributions. Be careful the limit can depend on $\phi$ so choose it one for all. The derivative is continuous on the space of distributions thus $(f \circ g)' =  \lim_{n \to \infty} g'f_n'(g(.))$